# Rails SImple From post to different controller create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, controller, simple-form

I have 3 models. User, Group, and Membership. User and Group have a has_many relationship through Membership. I want to be able to create the membership by clicking on a join button form the group show view.

Part of the Show view on the Groups Controller

```
= simple_form_for @membership, :url => memberships_path do |f|
  = f.input :group_id, :value => @group.id, :as => :hidden
  = f.submit "Join This Group!"
```

I set @membership in the groups show action with `@membership = Membership.new`
Just trying to figure out what I need to do to pass the from above to the create action on the membership controller. Right now it seem to be trying to pass it to the show action in the membership controller. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Edit:  The issue was not that this was not passing to membership. It was that it was not passing group_id to membership. The following is the fix to me issue

```
= simple_form_for @membership do |f|
  = f.input :group_id, :input_html => { :value => @group.id }, :as => :hidden
  = f.submit "Join This Group!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a @user instance variable set to the current users id, you can use

```
 simple_form_for [@user, @membership] do |f|
```

Comment: I selected this as the correct answer because it made me aware that my assignment of @membership = Membership.new was enough to set the rails form post to the create action on the membership controller. After that I realize my issue was totally different than the question I asked. Thank you.  (You can find my full fix in the edit on the original question)